# Crystal Reports asks password in Client systems

Tags: crystal-reports

This is the Login Info Method

```
private void SetLogonInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            LogInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "ServerName";
            LogInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "UserID";
            LogInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "Password";
            LogInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DataBase";
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

To create report I used this code

```
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = null;
            rptdoc = new ReportDocument();
            rptdoc.Load("REPORTS\\TC.rpt");
            crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula =selectionFormula;
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptdoc;
            rptdoc.Database.Tables[0].ApplyLogOnInfo(LogInfo);
```

It works well in server system, but if I use this in client systems, it asks for username and password. I'm using Crystal Reports 10. Moreover sometimes it asks for Username password in server system also. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing things in the wrong order. You need to do the login programmatically BEFORE you load the report on the viewer.

Additionally, I cannot stress enough that you need to test your program on the server machine and a test client machine before you release it to users.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...can u please provide me the correct order..?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is wrong username, password.
Check username, password and use the code below:

```ts
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
Tables CrTables;

//This is for Access Database
crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "" + "" +Application.StartupPath + "\\Database.mdb"; //access Db Path
crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "" + "" + Application.StartupPath + "\\Database.mdb";//access Db Path
crConnectionInfo.UserID = "ADMIN";
crConnectionInfo.Password = Program.DBPassword; //access password

//This is for Sql Server
crConnectionInfo.UserID = Program.Severuser; //username
crConnectionInfo.Password = Program.Password;//password
crConnectionInfo.ServerName = Program.server;//servername
crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Program.database;//database

string path = "" + Application.StartupPath + "\\supportingfiles\\Invoice.rpt";
cryRpt.Load(path);
CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
{
   crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
   crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
   CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
}

cryRpt.SetParameterValue("invoiceno", Program.billno);

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```